# Difference between pid controller and on-off controller?

Tags: control, pid-controller, system

I want to know difference between pid controller and on-off controller especially in regards to the operation of both?

The following link gives difference between pid controller and on-off controller ? Is thjs explanation correct?  I am bit confused from explanation of pid controller about what will happen when system temperature reaches setpoint

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-PID-controller-and-an-on-off-controller

If someone can explain the difference in his own words or simplifies the explanation given in above link

Comment: I always find that this is the best video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JFTJ2SS4xyA to explain what a PID controller is, its very low level and very practical, but trust me this only scratches the very tip of the iceberg, and the iceberg is MASSIVE when it comes to control systems.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing particular necessarily happens with a PID controller when the process variable reaches the setpoint. What happens depends on the history of how far it has been from the setpoint and on how fast it approaches the setpoint.

The amount of power the PID controller calls for depends on the distance from the setpoint (proportional term), how fast it is rising or falling (derivative term) and how long it has been loitering near the setpoint (integral term).

Answer (score 1):

With PID controller you get lower overshoot when properly tuned. PID controller may be unstable if not properly implemented - integral windup, and if not properly tuned. Therefore, if the system parameters change, the PID control may become unstable.

On the other hand the on/off controller is always stable, but it may have big overshoots, specially if the system has short response time. For example: you want to control temperature in a small oven with very powerful electric heater. In the on/off control the manipulated variable and system output is phase shifted by almost 180 degrees, thus the frequency is almost the resonance frequency of the system. But this oscillation is always stable, no matter if the system parameters change.

[image]